# Google App Engine Datastore: Turkish Characters won't sort properly

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using App Engine Python and Datastore will not sort Turkish characters properly. I cannot find a solution. Here is my problem:

```
yazarlar = Yazarlar.all().order('isim')
```

Well, this returns the field beginning with letter "ş" (a Turkish letter) at the end of the results. It should come right after S letter but it goes after Z, which is frustrating !

I could not find a proper solution on the internet so I'm desperately hoping that somebody around here might come up with one.

Comment: I had the same problem a year ago. You need a unicode collation, where the sorting is based on the locale. I do not know, if there is a Python solution yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of configurable collation, if you know the characters you want to deal with then having a second property on your model, 'isim_sortable', that replaces the extra characters with their ascii equivalent (ş -> 'sz' for example) should work.

Comment: You're right, Greg. I've already figured out that solution on my own. But thanks, anyway.